# Unable to configure PowerPiviot Service to existing SharePoint farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, administration, central-administration, farm-admin

I am configuring PowerPiviot service to existing sharepoint farm.And I see 2 errors below . Can any one do let me know how can I solve this below erros

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The messages are very clear. You're not installing this on a SharePoint server like you should be, and you're attempting to install it on a 32-bit OS. Here is a step-by-step for what I'm assuming is for a SharePoint 2010 farm:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210708%28v=sql.120%29.aspx